# How to use schematron validation in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, validation, xsd, schematron

I would like to validate a XML file against a schematron file I've. Is it possible to do it via Visual Studio 2010?

When I open XML file in Visual Studio, I am able to add XSD files which have schema defined but I would like to validate against schematron rules I've in a separate sch file.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to perform validation inside of the Visual Studio IDE, or that you would like to use Visual Studio to write a program which performs validation?

Comment: I would like to perform validation within VS itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating XML with Schematron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759417/validating-xml-with-schematron)